# Питон, работа с файлами

Tags: python, файлы

Начал изучать файлы в питоне,встретился с проблемами в решении задачи, вот ее формулировка:

Дан файл f, компоненты которого являются целыми числами.
Получить файл g, образованный из файла f
исключением повторных вхождений одного и того же числа.

```
f = open ("f.txt","r+")

n = f.read()
print(n)
lst=[]
lst.append(n)
lst = set(lst)

print(lst)
str1 = ''.join(lst)
g = open("g.txt","r+")
print(str1)
g.write(str1)

print(g)
```

Результат работы программы:

```
123, 0, 123, -5, 87, 0 - эти числа лежат у меня в файле
{'123, 0, 123, -5, 87, 0'}
123, 0, 123, -5, 87, 0
```

То есть как я понял, мне нужно заключить все числа в кавычки, чтобы убрать повторяющиеся с помощью set, но как это сделать?

Comment: У вас n = f.read() n это переменная строка, а её нужно перевести в список целых чисел.

Comment: вам надо разделить числа через кавычки, когда вы читаете файл, то в результате получаете одну строку, далее её надо разделить через split(',') на несколько строк, то есть получить массив строк(в данном случае в строках по числу)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем так. Строка с числами, которую вы получаете из файла - это строковая переменная. Вы правильно решили воспользоваться свойствами `set`, чтобы убрать дубликаты. Но для этого вам нужно разбить строку на элементы и уже их загнать в `set`:

```
import re #импорт модуля для работы  регулярными выражениями

data='123, 0, 123, -5, 87, 0' #ваша строка из файла
nums = set(re.findall('-*?\d+', data))#выбираем из этой строки только числа и загоняем их в set
print(nums) #печать результата
```

Получим:

> {'-5', '123', '0', '87'}

Обратите внимание, что в результате мы получили множество строковых переменных. Если вам нужны именно числа (и это более правильный вариант), то можно сделать так:

```
nums = set(map(int, re.findall('-*?\d+', data))) #выбираем из этой строки только числа
```

Тогда в результате получим:

> {0, 123, 87, -5}

И еще, советую сразу приучать себя работать с файлами через враппер `with`

**UPDATE** (per gil9red):
регексп `-*?\d+` выглядет избыточным, для решения поставленной задачи вполне хватит `-?\d+`.

Comment: всё отлично, но как из кортежа потом переформировать в начальный вид для вывода?

Comment: `-*?\d+` выглядит странно, зачем там `*`? Можно ведь просто `-?\d+`

Comment: @gil9red `-*` выглядит избыточно, согласен. Но не принципиально.

Comment: @ПётрКуртов не нужно ничего переформатировать. просто выводите сет на печать или в файл. Либо, если прям хочется получить именно строку, то воспользуйтесь методом join:  `', '.join(nums)` для первого варианта или `', '.join(map(str,nums))` - для второго.

Comment: Спасибо, а можно обьяснить что такое + и - в строке регулярки?
не могу найти информацию

Comment: Пётр, документации полно: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html А вообще, '-' - это просто "минус", а '+' - это модификатор, означающий совпадение предыдущего символа один и более раз.

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, вы хотите из файла `f` только читать, и в файл `g` только записывать. И так, вам не нужно `+` во втором параметре функции `open()`:

```
f = open("f.txt", "r")      # вместо f = open ("f.txt","r+")
g = open("g.txt", "w")      # вместо g = open("g.txt","r+")
```

Во вторых, лучше использовать блок with вместе с открытием файла - одно из преимуществ есть автоматическое закрытие файла после выхода из него:

```
with open("f.txt", "r") as f:
    n = f.read()

with open("g.txt", "w") as g:
    g.write(str1)
```

В третьих, хорошо выбрать лучшие имя для переменных (вместо `n`, `str1`, ...).

Во четвёртых, что это *«компоненты файла»*? Лучше бы было описать, каким образом числа в `f.txt` записаны - по *одном* числе в каждой строке или *более* чисел в каждой строке, каким образом числа *отделенны друг от друга*, ...

Но и наконец к вашему вопросу. Да, вы читаете и записываете *строки*, а не числа. Потому важно, каким образом числа в файл записаны. Когда взять пример, что все в одной строке и так:

> ```
> 123, 0, 123, -5, 87, 0
> ```

то после вашей команды `n = f.read()` нужно убрать знак конца строки, например так:

```
n = n.strip()
```

затем разбить её на части (но частями будут опять строки)

```
lst = n.split(", ")            # отделитель: запятая с пробелом
```

и затем каждую частичную строчку в этом списке превратить в число, что можно сделать так

```
numbers = [int(s) for s in lst]
```

или

```
numbers = map(int, lst)        # первый параметр - функция int - применится к всякому элементу lst
```

Answer (score 0):

Штатными средствами

```
def is_int(x):
    is_negative = x.startswith('-')
    element = x[1:] if is_negative else x
    return element.isdigit()


delimiter = ', '

data = '123, 0, f, 0.45, 1.48, 123, -5, 87, 0, a, b'

result_set = set(filter(is_int, data.split(delimiter)))

print(delimiter.join(result_set))       # -5, 87, 0, 123
```